# CSS-transition dosen't work on leave

Tags: css

I want the transition if i go out of the element, but it doesen't work.
It goes straight back to the original css. 
Just the hover work for me.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".neuesTicketSpalte").hover(
    function() {
      $(".textNeuesTicket").text("Erstelle ein neues Ticket");
    },
    function() {
      $(".textNeuesTicket").text("Neues Ticket");
    }
  );

});
```

```css
.neuesTicketSpalte .panelNeu {
  transition: border-left 1s ease;
}

.neuesTicketSpalte:hover .panelNeu {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid rgba(46, 143, 143, 1);
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  font-size: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="neuesTicketSpalte">
  
    <div class="panelNeu" title="Erstelle schnell ein neues Ticket">
      <p class="textNeuesTicket" style="font-size:5.0em; margin:auto auto;display: inline-block;">Neues Ticket
      </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to add the relevant HTML and turn it into a runnable Stack Snippet? There is an editor button for that.

Comment: try `transition: all 1s ease;`

Comment: Have EDIT my post @domdom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** add css property box-sizing to normal state so your  will remain its size.

**Second** add all border properties that you have already added to the hover state also to normal state.

there is working version code below, re-edit it for your purpose:

```html
<style>
.neuesTicketSpalte  .panelNeu {
  transition: border-left 1s ease;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#FFFF00;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  font-size: 0.3em;
  line-height:0.3em;
}

.neuesTicketSpalte:hover .panelNeu {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid rgba(46, 143, 143, 1);
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  font-size: 0.3em;
}
</style>

<body>

 <div class="neuesTicketSpalte">
     <div class="panelNeu">
         <p class="textNeuesTicket" style="font-size:5.0em; margin:auto auto;display: inline-block;">Neues Ticket
      </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `border-top`, `border-left` and `border-bottom` properties to both rules, then transition on `border` as well as `font-size`. Also note that you should remove the inline styles and add them to your CSS rules instead.

See here:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".neuesTicketSpalte").hover(
    function() {
      $(".textNeuesTicket").text("Erstelle ein neues Ticket");
    },
    function() {
      $(".textNeuesTicket").text("Neues Ticket");
    }
  );

});
```

```css
.neuesTicketSpalte .panelNeu {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 5em;
  border-top: 0 solid transparent;
  border-left: 0 solid rgba(46, 143, 143, 1);
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  transition: border 1s ease, font-size 1s ease;
}

.neuesTicketSpalte:hover .panelNeu {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid rgba(46, 143, 143, 1);
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  transition: border 1s ease, font-size 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="neuesTicketSpalte">
    <div class="panelNeu" title="Erstelle schnell ein neues Ticket">
      <p class="textNeuesTicket">Neues Ticket
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.neuesTicketSpalte .panelNeu {
  transition: border-left 1s ease;  
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid;
  font-size: 0.3em;
}

.neuesTicketSpalte:hover .panelNeu {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid rgba(46, 143, 143, 1);
  font-size: 0.3em;
}
```

You just need to set the default style for each of the animated properties.

Answer (score 0):

**PURE CSS SOLUTION**

You could actually drop the javascript altogether and use pure css:

```css
.panelNeu{
  position:relative;
  font-size:5em; 
  margin:auto;
  display: block;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  transition: border ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.panelNeu{
  border: 0 solid transparent;
}
.panelNeu::before{
  content:'Neues Ticket';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.neuesTicketSpalte:hover .panelNeu {
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid rgba(46, 143, 143, 1);
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
.neuesTicketSpalte:hover .panelNeu::before {
  content:'Erstelle ein neues Ticket';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="neuesTicketSpalte">  
  <div class="panelNeu" title="Erstelle schnell ein neues Ticket"></div>
</div>
```